# Return only matching subdocument from array of subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to return only the subdocument that has a matching e-mail. I've done what the documentation says [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/), I believe. Here's what I'm trying:

```
function lookupReferral(email) {
    return getConnection().then(db => db.collection('Referrals').findOne(
        {
            emails: {$elemMatch: {name: email}}
        },
        {
            "emails.$": 1 
        }
    ));
}
```

Here's an example of a document (I cut down the emails array for brevity):

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5b65979d84b8942e04f4e346"
},
"accountCode": "auth0|5b4de18d8bed60110409ded5",
"accountEmail": "abc@gmail.com",
"emails": [
    {
        "name": "a@ddd.dpp",
        "signedUp": false,
        "updated": {
            "$date": "2018-08-04T12:10:05.752Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "a@ddd.dpp",
        "signedUp": false,
        "updated": {
            "$date": "2018-08-04T12:10:05.752Z"
        }
    }
],
"created": {
    "$date": "2018-08-04T12:10:05.985Z"
},
"updated": {
    "$date": "2018-08-04T12:10:05.985Z"
}
```

For some reason it returns null (meaning it doesn't exists I guess?), but if I remove what I specifically want, then I get the entire document returned.

Comment: `db.collection('Referrals').findOne(
  {  emails: { $elemMatch: { name: "abc@gmail.com" }}},
  {  emails: { $elemMatch: { name: "abc@gmail.com" }}}
)` Try his

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Still returns null when I use an e-mail that exists in a subdocument { emails: {$elemMatch: {name: "azzz@zzz.dk"}}}, { emails {$elemMatch: {name: "azzz@zzz.dk"}}}

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
db.collection.find({
  emails: {
    $elemMatch: {
      name: "a@ddd.dpp"
    }
  }
},
{
  emails: {
    $elemMatch: {
      name: "a@ddd.dpp"
    }
  }
})
```

See the [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JeFwVTSot8s)

Comment: I tried it, doesn't work. It seems my problem is somewhere else than the query, then...

Comment: My exact thought. Good tool. :)